# How to override jQuery validate text color?

Tags: css, jquery-validate

I use jQuery Validate plugin to highlight errors. It replaces color of the text with red, which is OK for all elements except one - `.help-block`, it should remain blue.

Here is the code without error:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="place-of-birth">Place of birth</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <p class="help-block">Please input place of birth below, 2-80 symbols</p>
      <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="place-of-birth" name="place-of-birth" minlength="2" maxlength="80" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is with the error message:

```
<div class="control-group error"> <!-- STYLE IS CHANGED HERE -->
    <label class="control-label" for="place-of-birth">Place of birth</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <p class="help-block">Please input place of birth below, 2-80 symbols</p>
      <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="place-of-birth" name="place-of-birth" minlength="2" maxlength="80" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="help-block" generated="true" for="place-of-birth">Please enter at least 2 characters.</div> <!-- THIS LINE IS ADDED -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to override that with the following CSS:

```
.control-group .error .help-block { color: blue; }
```

but it didn't help. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/ukecog/6).

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it like this:

```
.control-group.error .help-block { color: blue; }
```

If you have two classes on one element there cannot be space between selectors. If there is a space it means that this class belongs to child tag.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS rule is this:

```
.control-group.error .input-prepend .add-on, .control-group.error .input-append .add-on {
  color: #B94A48;
  background-color: #F2DEDE;
  border-color: #B94A48;
}
```

Modify those values in either the `bootstrap.css` file or make your own.